# Dojo script (fx.xd.js) not working IE

Tags: dojo

I've been teaching myself Dojo over the last few days.

However, if you look at the following page:

http://www.mechanic-one.suburban-glory.com/

You'll see that the simple script in the header doesn't work in IE

I get the following message:

Message: 'duration' is null or not an object
Line: 8
Char: 622
Code: 0
URI: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.3.2/dojo/fx.xd.js

Why is this so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an extra comma in your source code. It's valid in Firefox, but not in IE.

Remove the comma after following code, it should work fine.

```
 dojo.fadeIn({
 node : link, 
 duration: 300,
 easing: easingFunction
}),
```